# What's the quickest way to lookup numbers?

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures, integer, big-o

I am storing numbers (in the range from 1 to less than 100,000) and then getting called with a number as an argument and having to use that as a key in a lookup. In the past, when getting short char* strings as keys to lookup I have used a trie implementation. I wonder if I should use one as well for numbers of if maybe there are some faster ways to look into/consider/investigate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really depends on what you're trying to do.

If you have a lot of memory, you could just build an array with 100,000 elements and just use the number as an index when looking into the table.  This is probably the fastest approach (lookups are all O(1) with extremely low constant factors), though it's not the most memory-efficient.  If memory is scarce, a standard hash table would be a good compromise; you get expected O(1) runtime for all operations.

If you need to be able to do queries of the form "what number is closest to x?," then you might want to use a balanced binary search tree that holds the integers.  This lets you do successor and predecessor searches and lookups in time O(log n).  If you're interested in trying out a much more complex data structure, you can use a [van Emde Boas tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree), which can do insertions, deletions, lookups, predecessor, and successor searches in time O(log log U), where U is the maximum possible value.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh a straight up array is not a bad idea! I actually know that 100000 is a reasonable upper bound

Comment: You must take into account that if multiple objects have a common key, collision-solving's cost can be pretty big.

Comment: It's worth noting that if your elements are fairly sparse within the 100,000 elements, this is not very cache efficient. Using the number as a hash and modding it then increases the number of operations to look up, but if it fits everything in a lower level of cache you may still get big speedups. Of course, if you're only storing a pointer to some other structure, a 100k-pointer array is only 800kb.

Comment: Rather than an array of size 100,000, a bitmap would be better, which could very well be more space efficient than a hashmap if the data is fairly dense.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a hashtable for this. Each value would be placed in a unique bucket that you can reference using your key. If your data can be organized in this manner this will be the fastest look up.

Comment: The thing is the cost of the hash is nontrivial, even if I use a super fast hash like FNV, whereas generally with short strings or knowing the properties of my keys (they are small numbers) i can take advantage of small tries with few jumps that avoid cache misses

Comment: One of hashtable versions is a direct-addressing table, in which "hashing" cost is trivial indeed. It may work fine, unless the possibility of having multiple objects with the same key is high.

Comment: key to value is unique, direct addressing table is the same as the above answer which yes i agree would be the fastest way